# Flickr or 500px or some random photo slideshow program

Tags: photography, slideshow

I'm looking for some kind of application that only has some simple needs:

- I want it to check 500px or Flickr or some photography site(s) for new/random photos. Preferably with the option to filter out NSFW photos.
- It displays a random new photo every N seconds. I'm fine if it's not configurable
- It needs to be able to run on Linux. It's fine if it runs in the web browser.

Do you know of any software like that?